# Add a when() clause to a nested foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, nested

I am trying to build a nested foreach loop in R that filter some cases that I know are going to fail and return a empty list. The code is something like:

```
TASK <- foreach (i = 1:MAX,.combine='rbind') %:%
          foreach (j = 1:MAX,.combine='rbind') %:%
            when( OD[i,j] >= MIN) ) %dopar%
{ 
  do things ...
}
```

the main problem is that i get the following error

> Error: At least one matching condition is needed.

I have tried even with when(TRUE) and I always get the same error. The nested foreach loops works perfectly without the when clause ( provided that my first instruction is to check it ).

Can you include a when() clause inside a nested foreach? I have searched the internet and the documentation and all examples are with single foreach constructs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the most recent CRAN version solves the issue, have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the last version allows to do that Thanks for pointing me to this! Nevertheless, I cannot set this as "solved" as you have no "answered" :S It is OK to leave this as it is?

Comment: No problem man, glad to help. I inserted an answer, so that you can mark it as "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent CRAN version (1.5.1) solved the issue.